# Recover truecrypt partition without MBR + recovery disk?

Tags: truecrypt, bootloader, mbr, filesystem-corruption, rescue

I destroyed my mbr and have no truecrypt rescue disk. However, I do know my password and my encryption setup (e.g. hashing functions and ciphers used).

This happened after an upgrade to version 7.0a of truecrypt. I still have the old bootloader for the 6.3a version, using the same crypto setup. However when I try overwriting the mbr with the old bootloader I get the "corrupt bootloader insert rescue disk" message.

Is there any way I can recover my data?

EDIT: The question should probably be, "is there any way to restore the bootloader". I can get to my data running ubuntu of an USB stick with truecrypt. Not much help though because I can't boot the OS.